# First jQuery .animate() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am very new to jQuery, JavaScript, etc
I have been working on trying to get a couple of animations going:

Currently I have a partial working demo located here: http://jsbin.com/uwonun/64/

Thanks to jwags, the 2nd .animate() works.

I have been trying to implement the same animation effect so that I can replace the .slideDown().

My latest attempt to get it working can be found here: http://jsbin.com/OYebomEB/1/

Please be aware that as continu to work on this, the code will change.

```
function anim_loop(index) {
  $(elements[index]).css({top: 0, display: 'none'}).animate({top: -75},1000, function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $self.animate({top: $(window).height() + 10}, 1000);
        anim_loop((index + 1) % elements.length);
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

Comment: so you are hiding it and then animating it? that seems like you'll never actually see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `display:none`, but never show it up after.

Use `css('display','block')` in your `setTimeout()`, before `animate()`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $self.css('display','block').animate({top: $(window).height() + 10}, 1000);
        anim_loop((index + 1) % elements.length);
    }, 3000);
});
```

You can make it appear smoothly by setting `opacity:0` at the initialization, and `opacity:1` in your second `animate()` ;)

### Edit

To get the first loop working as the others, you have to display your elements before they render onscreen, by setting `display:block` before the `animate()` :

```
function anim_loop(index) {
  $(elements[index]).css({top:-75, display: 'block'}).animate({top: '+0'},1000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
$self.animate({top: $(window).height() + 10}, 1000);
            anim_loop((index + 1) % elements.length);
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have managed to get it working almost. However, on the first loop it does not work correctly.

http://jsbin.com/OYebomEB/2/

It just goes through it without pausing

Comment: Perfect thanks. Moving it there also made the transitions appear smoother too.